# C++ Editing Text File

Tags: c++, file, text-files, edit

The problem is the data in a text file editing. The text file contains five columns.

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

1 2 4 4 1
2 3 4 4 3
3 4 5 0 0
```

The goal would be to move in columns 4 and 5 (values​​> 0) in columns 1 and 2 above or to follow up:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

1 2 4 0 0
2 3 4 0 0
3 4 5 0 0
4 1 0 0 0
4 3 0 0 0
```

How to achieve this? Can somebody show me an example how to do this with C++ `std::vector`?

That would be much appreciated.

Comment: Only theory. When I can read numbers s1, s2, s3, s4, s5:
 add to table t1 values s1, s2, s3, 0, 0
 add to table t2 values s4, s5, 0, 0, 0
when table t2 end has 0, 0, 0, 0, 0:
 remove table t2 last row
print table t1
print table t2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Joachim. Additionally, use `back_inserter`, `istream_iterator` and `stringstream` to make your life easier when reading in your file:

```
vector<vector<double> > contents;

/* read file */
{
    ifstream inFile( "data.txt" );
    for ( string line; inFile; getline( inFile, line ) ) {
        stringstream line_stream( line );
        vector<double> row;
        copy( istream_iterator<double>( line_stream ), istream_iterator<double>(),
            back_inserter(row) );
        contents.push_back( row );
    }
}
```

That will read in the whole file into `contents`. You'll need to include `sstream`, `algorithm`, `iterator`, `iosrteam`, `fstream`, `string` and `vector`.

Now you can easily process your file with a `for` loop and accessing the numbers with `contents[i][j]`. If I understand you correctly this is what I think you want to do:

```
/* process file */
unsigned int n = contents.size();
for ( unsigned int i=0; i < n; ++i ) {
    vector<double> row( 5, 0. );
    bool add_row = false;
    if ( contents[i].size() >= 5 ) {
        for ( unsigned int j=3; j<4; ++j ) {
            double value = contents[i][j];
            contents[i][j] = 0.;
            if ( value > 0 ) {
                add_row = true;
                row[j-3] = value;
            }
        }
        if ( add_row == true ) {
            contents.push_back( row );
        }
    }
}
```

Now to write the file to stdout, simply:

```
/* write file */
for ( unsigned int i=0; i < contents.size(); ++i ) {
    copy( contents[i].begin(), contents[i].end(), ostream_iterator<double>( cout, " " ) );
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a vector of vectors. For each line, read each number into a sub-vector. Then write out the three first values of each sub-vector, followed by the last two values of each sub-vector.

Comment: I should learn more about vectors, can you provide an example? That would be very nice.

Comment: You can start here http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm

Comment: @user2404495 Start by reading e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), and then do some simple experiments (adding elements to a vector, removing elements, iterating over a vector in different ways, using different types as base (including complex classes)).

Comment: @user2404495 for your problem, you might also want to read about [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter). All those are very useful for the first part (reading and pushing into vectors).